# adding together two 2d arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble this problem regarding 2d arrays. We must create a javascript function addArrays(al, a2) which takes in two 2d arrays of numbers, a1 and a2 and returns their "sum" in the sense of the matrix sum. If If a is array with the sum, then, for all rows i and all columns j, a[i][j] = a1[i][j] + a2[i][j].

I am completely stumped I am pretty sure my logic to find the sum is right but I don't know if anything is actually stored in the sum array or what this error means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var sum = new Array(a1.length);
for (var k = 0; k<sum.length; k++) {
    sum[k] = new Array(sum.length);
}

for (var l = 0; l<sum.length; l++) {
    for (var m = 0; m<sum.length[l]; m++) {
        sum[l][m].push(a1[l][m] + a2[l][m]);
    }
}

return sum;
```

We are given a test file:

```
 function start() {  
  var ar1 = [[1,2], [3,4]],
  ar11 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
  ar12 = [[1,2,3], [3,4]],

  ar2 = [[6,7], [8,9]],
  ar21 = [[6,7], [8,9], [19,11]],
  ar22 = [[6,7], [8,9,10]],

  ar;

  try {
     alert( addArrays(ar1, ar2).toSource() );
  }
  catch (e) {
      alert( e );
  }}
```

When I run the program I keep getting the error:
 TypeError: addArrays(...).toSource is not a function

Comment: `toSource` is non-standard and doesn't work in your browser. Try `console.log(addArrays(ar1, ar2))`.

Comment: @georg it needs to be within alert. How do I do this with console.log?

Comment: [Chrome using the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) or [Firefox web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Comment: As @georg points out, `toSource()` is a non-standard function that is not equally supported by browsers.  [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource).  According to the spec - Firefox appears to be the only browser with confirmed support.

Comment: just do alert( JSON.stringify(addArrays(ar1, ar2)) );

Comment: I would also ask why your instructor is using non-standard JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

> error: TypeError: addArrays(...).toSource is not a function

Means it cannot find the function `toSource` on what is beign returned by `addArrays`. [Object.toSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) is not part of any standard and should not be used.

From MDN

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Looking at the output of toSource it looks similar to JSON. You can change the test to utilize [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to achieve a similar output.

```
 function start() {  
  var ar1 = [[1,2], [3,4]],
  ar11 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
  ar12 = [[1,2,3], [3,4]],

  ar2 = [[6,7], [8,9]],
  ar21 = [[6,7], [8,9], [19,11]],
  ar22 = [[6,7], [8,9,10]],

  ar;

  try {
     alert( JSON.stringify(addArrays(ar1, ar2)) );
  }
  catch (e) {
      alert( e );
  }}
```

Comment: @user2415266 I typed it before I saw the comments, great minds think alike!

Comment: wasn't really meant as critique, you put quite some effort into the answer

Comment: @user2415266 I wasn't taking it as such :)

Comment: @Austin Thank you! this worked, but now when I run it the text in the alert box says, "[[null,null],[null,null]]". Is my method calculating and creating the sum matrix correct?

Answer (score 2):

For same size arrays you can invent some Array method like `Array.prototype.matriceSum()` as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.matriceSum = function(a) {
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = c.reduce((f,s,j) => (f[j]+= s,f),p[i]),p),a.slice());
};
var a1 = [[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[4,5,6]],
    a2 = [[6,6,6],[9,8,7],[6,5,4]];
    a3 = a1.matriceSum(a2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a3));
```

This won't mutate the array it's called upon and return a new 2D array with the matrix addition of the two 2D arrays.